# How do I access the ModelState from within my View (aspx page)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, view, modelstate

How do I access the ModelState from within my View (aspx page)?

Comment: I don't think you should.  That sort of thing should happen in the Controller.

Comment: I need to know if my ModelState is valid. 

I don't want to do this:

<% if (Html.ValidationSummary() != null) %>
<% { %>
<p class="validation-summary-errors">
Your message was not sent. Please correct the errors below and try again.
</p>
<% } %>

Instead I want to do this:

<% if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{ %>
<p class="validation-summary-errors">
Your message was not sent. Please correct the errors below and try again.
</p>
<%} %>

Comment: That sounds like a good enough reason to access ModelState

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with accessing ModelState in the view.  It's part of ViewData.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Use `ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState`.

Comment: Also worthy to note that you can just do `ViewData.ModelState` and if you want to display some conditional markup on errors you can do like this: `@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)`