# check member existence in Mvc ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewbag

Sometimes I have to check the existence of a member inside the ViewBag from inside an Mvc View, to see if for any problem the action forgot to assign the member. Inside my Razor View I have:

```
@if(ViewBag.Utente.Ruolo.SysAdmin)
```

how can I check that `ViewBag.Utente` is defined?

Answer (score 4):

You must check all objects are null or not. `Utente`, `Utente.Ruolo` and `Utente.Ruolo.SysAdmin` may be null:

```
@if (ViewBag.Utente != null)
{
  if (ViewBag.Utente.Ruolo != null)
  {
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Utente.Ruolo.SysAdmin))
     {
       //ViewBag.Utente.Ruolo.SysAdmin has value..you can use it 
     }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As simple as this:

```
@if (ViewBag.Utente != null)
{
   // some code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MVC4 you can use

```
@if (ViewBag.Utente != null)
```

For previous versions take a look at those answers:

[Checking to see if ViewBag has a property or not, to conditionally inject JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640927/checking-to-see-if-viewbag-has-a-property-or-not-to-conditionally-inject-javasc)

Answer (score 1):

You can you use it;

```
@if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Utente.Ruolo.SysAdmin))
{

}
```

But if you want to check your users are confirmed or not, I think it is not a good way..