# How to check if ViewBag property is null or not exists

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a requirement to execute a script in document.ready function if viewbag property is null or not exists. Below is the code I wrote to check if viewbag property not exists.

I used recommned approached where you `@ViewBag.Property!=null` but when I do that I get an error saying name property does not exist in current context,

```
@section scripts {

@if ((bool)ViewData.ContainsKey("FormSubmitFlag") == false)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var pageVisitCount = sessionStorage.getItem("personalDetailsVisitCount");
            if (pageVisitCount == null) {
                $("#personal-details-form").trigger('reset');
                sessionStorage.setItem("personalDetailsVisitCount", "1");
            }
            else {
                var validator = $("#personal-details-form").validate();
                validator.form();
                cat.personaldetails.validate();
            }
        });
    </script>
}

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Check in html what output this line of code `@if ((bool)ViewData.ContainsKey("FormSubmitFlag") == false)` generates. It would give you better Idea what is going wrong.

Comment: using `@ViewBag.Property!=null` should be fine. How were you using it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking to see if ViewBag has a property or not, to conditionally inject JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640927/checking-to-see-if-viewbag-has-a-property-or-not-to-conditionally-inject-javasc)

Comment: Check this: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Check-if-ViewBag-property-is-null-or-not-exists-in-Net-MVC

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can check for `null` and execute your script.

```
@if (ViewBag.YourKey== null)
{
 //your code   
}
```

This will check that `ViewBag.YourKey` is null if you want to check it for not null you can change the if condition.