# checking if a viewbag list is null or empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I can't check if my list length is 0. The code works if I remove the second part of the or; only check if the list is null.

```
@{
    @if( ViewBag.somelist != null || Enumerable.Count(ViewBag.somelist) == 0)
    {
        <p>list not null or empty</p>
    }
    @else
    {
        <p>list is empty</p>
    }
}
```

what I've tried:

- Enumerable.Count(ViewBag.somelist) <1
- ViewBag.somelist.Count() == 0
- 

```
var somelist=Viewbag.somelist.Count;
@if( ViewBag.bbM9and10 != null || somelist == 0){}
```

also the interchangables to check if list is empty:
*>=0, <=0, <1, >=1*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313324/how-to-check-if-viewbag-property-is-null-or-not-exists/28313648

Comment: thats only checking if the list null. my code already does that. I want to also check if the length of my list is equal to zero

Comment: Should that not check if the list != null or the list count is greater than 0, not equal to zero

Comment: Alternatively it would be if(Not Null AND Count > 0)

Comment: my viewbag is created somewhere along the line in my code. it isn't always present. That is the reason I'm checking if it is null. once it is created however. I want to check if the list is empty if enough indexes are removed to make the list length zero

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just use [Any()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-5.0) here, replacing your `||` for an `&&` as mentioned in the comments, because you're checking if the list is not null **and** not empty:

```
@{
    @if(ViewBag.somelist != null && ViewBag.somelist.Any())
    {
        <p>list not null or empty</p>
    }
    @else
    {
        <p>list is empty</p>
    }
}
```

You can safely call it because the execution will never hit that point if `somelist` is null.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your code is **||** operator. For **||** operator when first statement is true or false, second statement will always gets  executed. In your case, If  **ViewBag.somelist** is null, second statement will also gets executed and it will then throw **ArgumentNullException**. To overcome this use **&&** in place of **||**. It will act as a short circuit and when first statement is true only then second will get executed else it execution will move to next line.