# PartialView for displaying Modal Error Message based on ViewBag

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing a `MVC 5` app with the [SweetAlert 2 plugin](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/).

My Goal: When an error occurs anywhere in my app I'd like to display a (centralized, sweetalert) modal dialog with a title/message.

I created a PartialView called "_ModalError" and referenced this in the bottom of my main, shared "_Layout" view. Basically so this partial view will be enabled for every page.

I then created a simple Error class...

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class MyError
    {
        public string ErrorTitle { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I was thinking that, whenever I get an error, I would instantiate a new MyError object, set the appropriate ErrorTitle and ErrorMessage properties, then set ViewBag.Error to this MyError object.

```
private MyError err = new MyError();
err.ErrorMessage = "Your information was not valid. Please re-check everything.";
err.ErrorTitle = "Error!";
ViewBag.Error = err;
```

Then, in javascript, whenever the _ModalError (the page) loads, it would look to see if ViewBag.Error exists. If so, an error occurred, so display it. Here's what I have so far....

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        if (@ViewBag.Error != null) {
            swal(
                @ViewBag.Error.ErrorTitle, 
                @ViewBag.Error.ErrorMessage,
                'error'
            );
    };
</script>
```

The problem is that when the page first loads I get this error when it hits the viewbag code...

```
Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference.
```

I'm trying to access `ViewBag` but apparently it doesn't exist at first, which makes sense. But, checking to see if it's null isn't really working. Do you know why this is? Any suggestions? Is this a faulty, crazy, or over-kill solution?

******** SOLUTION ********

Here's the solution. Thanks to Stephen Muecke (below) for the Json.Encode advice! I hope this is helpful to someone else!

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var error = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Error));
    if (error != null) {
        swal(
            error.ErrorTitle,
            error.ErrorMessage,
            'error'
        );
    }
})
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640927/checking-to-see-if-viewbag-has-a-property-or-not-to-conditionally-inject-javasc

Comment: you need to wrap `@ViewBag.Error.ErrorTitle` and `@ViewBag.Error.ErrorMessage` in quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the view, so `@ViewBag.Error.ErrorTitle,` and `@ViewBag.Error.ErrorMessage` are evaluated on the server, and if `@ViewBag.Error` is `null`, the exception is throw because you cannot access a property of a `null` object. (it does not stop evaluating it just because its in a javascript `if` statement - that is client side code and does not even exist at that point)

Instead, assign the `Error` object to a javascript object, and then test it in you `if` block

```
$(function() {
    // Assign to a javascript variable
    var error = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Error))
    if (!error) {
        swal(
            error.ErrorTitle, 
            error.ErrorMessage,
            'error'
        );
    }
}
```

You should also consider using a base view model containing your `Error` object rather than passing it around in a `ViewBag` property.

Comment: He needs first to determine if `ViewBag` has `Error` property.

Comment: @Igor. That is exactly what `if (!error) {` does :)

Comment: Hm, ok. I was under the impression that accessing non-existing property of a dynamic object is a no-no.

Comment: @Igor, Its not accessing _a non-existing property of a dynamic object_. The first line of code evaluates to either `null` (if `ViewBag.Error` has not been assigned) or to `{ ErrorTitle: 'Error!', ErrorMessage: 'Your information was .... ' }` if it has. Its then javascript that is accessing the values of the properties (not razor)

Comment: @StephenMuecke perfect! Thanks!